# how to compare & call multiple conntionstring name in DBContext MVC

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

How to compare string 'location' & call multiple connection string name in DBContext if string matched with value and also pass string value from Controller to DBContext. Basically i want to connect different database to get result.

1) Web.config file

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="mum_Conn" connectionString="my connection string" />
  <add name="chd_Conn" connectionString="my connection string" />
  <add name="hyd_Conn" connectionString="my connection string" />
  <add name="goa_Conn" connectionString="my connection string" />
  <add name="pun_Conn" connectionString="my connection string" />
</connectionStrings>
```

2) DBContext : -

```
public class MasterDal: DbContext
{

    static MasterDal()
     {
         Database.SetInitializer<MasterDal>(null);
     }


   public MasterDal() : base("mum_Conn") { }


    public DbSet<ProjectListModel> prjlstModel { get; set; }


    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Entity<ProjectListModel>().ToTable("tbl_projects");
    }


}
```

3) Controller : -

```
public class FMPDataController : Controller
{

    public ActionResult FMP_Report()
    {   
        MasterViewModel  obj = new MasterViewModel();
        MasterDal dal = new MasterDal();
        List<ProjectListModel> prjColl = new List<ProjectListModel>();
        try
        {
            string name = @Session["username"].ToString();
            if (System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("mis_rpt_access").Contains(name))
            {
                prjColl = (from x in dal.prjlstModel
                           orderby  x.codes select x).ToList<ProjectListModel>();
                obj.projectlist = prjColl;
            }
            else
            {
               prjColl = (from x in dal.prjlstModel
                          where x.is_active == 1 orderby x.codes
                           select x).ToList<ProjectListModel>();
                obj.projectlist = prjColl;
            }                
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write("<script>alert('" + ex.Message + "');</script>");
        }

        return View(obj);
    }

}
```

4) Result I want in DBContext (i:e class MasterDal: DbContext)

```
 if (location.equal("MUM"))
 { 
    // call Mumbai DBConnection string name
 }
 else if (location.equal("HYD"))
 {
    //call Hyderabad DBConnection string name
 }
```

Comment: you have already hardcoded dbcontext to "mum_Conn"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could overload the DbContext's constructor with the dynamic connection string

```
public class MasterDal : DbContext
    {
        public MasterDal(string nameOrConnectionString) : base(nameOrConnectionString)
        {

        }
       // DbSet &  OnModelCreating etc 
    }
```

& then invoke dal in Controller as required

```
if (location.equal("MUM"))
 { 
    MasterDal dal = new MasterDal("mum_Conn");
   // do  mumbai related whatever 
 }
 else if (location.equal("HYD"))
 {
     MasterDal dal = new MasterDal("hyd_Conn");
 }
```